# No voice feedback when using Siri with American accent in iOS 9.0.2

Tags: iphone, siri, ios, voice-dictation

I'm using Siri with American accent in iOS 9.0.2. But it doesn't have voice feedback, even though in navigation mode in Maps. Once I switch to British accent, Siri speaks. Is that a bug for Siri in recent iOS update?

Answer (score 1):

Siri and "Speech" on iOS seem to be tangled since iOS 9. Here's how to fix it:

Go to **Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Speech -> Voices -> English -> and download both "Siri Female (Enhanced)" and "Alex".**

**Note**: Make sure to stay in the settings app while the download is completing. If you leave the app or go to another page within settings, the download will cancel.

Let me know if that works ;).

Comment: It didn't work. And every time I entered the "English" page, it re-download **Siri Female(Enhanced)** again. :(

Comment: chenghuayang, you need to stay in the settings app while the download is completing. If you leave the app or go to another page within settings, the download will cancel.

Comment: I had this issue, and downloading the voice might have fixed it. Also try changing voice feedback (General -> Siri -> Voice Feedback) to Control with ring-switch, then set it back to Always On

Answer (score 0):

I had the same result. In fact the Siri Female voice enhanced did finish downloading. But my phone does not retain it. Not sure if it is hardware but I know it worked before I updated it.
And tried every combination and permutation. So British or Australian accents work but not American accent!

Comment: That's my problem, too. :(

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Today after updating the ios the American Siri voice is back and working.